# No database connection on Heroku even after successful rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I just ran `rake db:migrate` successfully on Heroku on my first deploy of my Rails 4 app:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.7124
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
Migrating to DeviseCreateUsers (20131223210005)
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0431s
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0093s
-- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0185s
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrated (0.0716s) =====================================

Migrating to AddNameToUsers (20131223210006)
==  AddNameToUsers: migrating =================================================
-- add_column(:users, :name, :string)
   -> 0.0060s
==  AddNameToUsers: migrated (0.0062s) ========================================

Migrating to AddConfirmableToUsers (20131223210008)
==  AddConfirmableToUsers: migrating ==========================================
-- add_column(:users, :confirmation_token, :string)
   -> 0.0030s
-- add_column(:users, :confirmed_at, :datetime)
   -> 0.0016s
-- add_column(:users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime)
   -> 0.0018s
-- add_column(:users, :unconfirmed_email, :string)
   -> 0.0016s
==  AddConfirmableToUsers: migrated (0.0085s) =================================

Migrating to RolifyCreateRoles (20131223210011)
==  RolifyCreateRoles: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:roles)
   -> 0.0139s
-- create_table(:users_roles, {:id=>false})
   -> 0.0021s
-- add_index(:roles, :name)
   -> 0.0093s
-- add_index(:roles, [:name, :resource_type, :resource_id])
   -> 0.0143s
-- add_index(:users_roles, [:user_id, :role_id])
   -> 0.0095s
==  RolifyCreateRoles: migrated (0.0502s) =====================================
```

Now when I go to the console - `heroku run console` and try to access any of the models I get a `no database connection` message.

```
$ heroku run console
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.9633
Loading production environment (Rails 4.0.2)
irb(main):001:0> User
=> User(no database connection)
irb(main):002:0> User
=> User(no database connection)
irb(main):003:0> exit
```

This is the concatenated version (for brevity) of my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'devise'
gem 'pg'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'thin'
gem "rails_admin"
gem "friendly_id"

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'  
  gem 'annotate', :git => 'git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git'
  gem 'sextant'
end

group :production do
  gem "rails_12factor"  
end

ruby '2.0.0'
```

My `database.yml` file:

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
development:
  adapter:  postgresql
  host:     localhost
  encoding: unicode
  database: mydbname
  pool:     5
  username: myusername
  password:
  template: template0

test:
  adapter:  postgresql
  host:     localhost
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_test_db
  pool:     5
  username: myusername
  password:
  template: template0

production:
  adapter:  postgresql
  host:     localhost
  encoding: unicode
  database: myproductiondb
  pool:     5
  password:
  template: template0
```

Not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`no database connection` in the console doesn't mean the connection is failing. It simply means that Rails hasn't connected to the database (yet) probably because there was no need.

You can see if the connection works by trying to perform a query. For instance

```
User.all
```

and see if it raises any error.

In order to see the attributes, you can trigger `inspect` explicitly on the model

```
User.inspect
```

Comment: Ahhh....ok....well I am used to seeing the AR object when I do `User` in Rails 3.x. How do I see that now? `User.all` works....btw. i.e. I want to see all the attributes of a `User` object. How do I do that now?

Comment: `User.inspect` should trigger it.